# multiple print doc file on button click

Tags: asp.net

I want to print multiple doc file on button click.I am using this code

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(txtFileName.Text.Trim());     
info.Verb = "Print";     
info.CreateNoWindow = true;     
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;     
Process.Start(info);
```

and the code is working fine in my application,but after publishing the application on the server ,i am unable to access the functionality.thanks in advance

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: no.I have also use try,catch,but its not showing any exception.when i click print button,my page loading ,but its not giving any output,nor any exception or error.please help me.i am trying to resolve this since 1 week.